# Remember me half working - Android

Tags: android

I can't figure out why if I hit the check box "Remember Me", the app will remember only the Name and not the Last Name. I probably forgot something, but I can't actually find what.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    c = this;

    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    etLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastNameEditText);
    etTavolo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tavoloEditText);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cbLogin);

    loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
    loginPrefsEditor = loginPreferences.edit();
    saveLogin = loginPreferences.getBoolean("saveLogin", false);

    if (saveLogin == true) {
        etName.setText(loginPreferences.getString("Name", ""));
        etLastName.setText(loginPreferences.getString("Last Name", ""));
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }


    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //REMEMBER ME CHECK BOX
            if (v == btnLogin) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(etName.getWindowToken(), 0);

                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String lastName = etLastName.getText().toString();
                String tavolo = etTavolo.getText().toString();

                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    loginPrefsEditor.putBoolean("saveLogin", true);
                    loginPrefsEditor.putString("Name", name);
                    loginPrefsEditor.putString("Last name", lastName);
                    loginPrefsEditor.commit();
                } else {
                    loginPrefsEditor.clear();
                    loginPrefsEditor.commit();
                }
```

the rest of the code is not needed for this problem.

Comment: Are you sure that you are loading the last name out of the prefs when it opens?

Comment: Maybe don't name your variable with a space in it.  Try "LastName".

Comment: pro-tip: define constants for your keys. That will avoid you many such issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
etLastName.setText(loginPreferences.getString("Last Name", ""));

loginPrefsEditor.putString("Last name", lastName);
```

"N" is different cases here